# C - Correct way to write to a file the contents of a buffer?

Tags: c, file, sockets, udp, buffer

I'm currently using fwrite() to write the contents of a char[] buffer to a text file.

The documentation at [this link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fwrite.htm) shows that size_t for the size is needed, but **would an integer make a difference**? My output file shows up blank.

For reference, here is a snippet of what I have:

```
char* output_file;
int buffer_size = 20;

int sockfd = 0;
int bitsReceived = 0;
int totalBitsReceived = 0;

char recvBuffer[buffer_size];

struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, client_addr;
socklen_t alen = sizeof(serv_addr);

memset(recvBuffer, '0', sizeof(recvBuffer));
memset((char *)&serv_addr,0,sizeof(serv_addr)); 

serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(server_port);
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(server_ip);

if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == -1) {
    perror("Cannot create socket");
    return 0;
}

/* Open the input file to read */
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen(input_file, "r");
size_t nread;

if (fp == NULL) {
    perror("Error: ");
    return(-1);
}

FILE *outputFilep;
outputFilep = fopen(output_file, "w");

bzero(recvBuffer, buffer_size);

/* Read input from server and write it to output file */
while((bitsReceived = recvfrom(sockfd, recvBuffer, buffer_size, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, &alen)) > 0) {
    totalBitsReceived += bitsReceived;
    size_t m = fwrite(recvBuffer, sizeof(char), (size_t)bitsReceived, outputFilep);

    if (m < 0) {
        perror("Error: ");
    }       
}
```

Comment: `size_t` is just an unsigned integer

Comment: You are sending only 20-byte datagrams?  Seems a bit small for file transfer.  Then again, using UDP seems a bit strange for file transfer.  Also, cargo-cult 'bzero':(

Answer (score 2):

It would not, you can use an `int` — as long as you're sure that it will never be negative because that would be a problem.

The negative `-1` value could be returned as an error indicator. So you **must** check for it right after calling `recvfrom()`.

Comment: There's a minor caveat: as long as you have a prototype declaration for `fwrite()` in scope.  For `fwrite()`, that isn't going to be a problem (or is extraordinarily unlikely to be a problem), but in the general case, passing an `int` to a function that expects a `size_t` can cause trouble if (as on Unix-based 64-bit systems at least) `sizeof(int) == 4` and `sizeof(size_t) == 8` and there is no prototype in scope to force the conversion from `int` to `size_t`.  It will generate compiler warnings with more stringent compilation options, too.